# 내다 놓다 change of 내다?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

I have recently learned the vocabulary 쓰레기를 내다 놓다 as to take out the trash.

However in the book the following sentence occurs: 다림질이나 쓰레기도 분리해서 내어 놓아야 한다.

My question would be: why did they change the grammatical form of the 내다? I assume they used the 아/어 놓다 grammar pattern, but is possible for vocabularies in this style (-다 -다, like 갖다 오다) to change the previous verb form? What would be the rules for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

내어 놓다 and 내다 놓다 are very close in meaning, but they are two different constructs.

- 내어 놓다 = 내다 + -아/어 놓다 -> 내어놓다 (it has actually become a single word 내어놓다 with no space in it, and it usually contracts to 내놓다)
- 내다 놓다 = 내다 + -아/어다가 + 놓다 -> 내어다가 놓다 -> 내다가 놓다 -> 내다 놓다.

-아/어다(가) is a verb ending that signifies one action immediately being followed by another.  It is very common in everyday conversation, as in 갔다 오다 (not 갖다 오다 as you spelled), 갖다 놓다, and so on. It usually implies movement between the first and second action.

So 내어놓다 simply means putting it out, while 내다 놓다 sounds like taking it out to put it somewhere farther and leaving it there.

Both 내(어)놓다 and 내다 놓다 are frequently used.  In apartment living, phrases like 오늘 쓰레기 내놔야(=내(어)놓아야) 돼 or 오늘 쓰레기 내다 놓는 날이야 are common occurrences.  So you'll encounter both expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)